# android- custom listview with edittext

Tags: android

I have a custom listView with editText in each row to carry value entered by the user.
and i have a button next to the listview which onclick will add up the editText value from all the rows from the list.

can anyone give me some link for some clue.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.PeriodicSync;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.text.InputFilter.LengthFilter;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class NRSessionScheduleFragmentOne extends ListFragment {

        String[] dummyVal = new String[] { "hello", "how", "are", "u", "how",
                "are", "u", "how", "are" };
        ListView parentList;
        int addVal;
        EditText period;

        private NRSessionFragmentHolder parentobj;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nrtpsessiontopics, container, false);
            return v;
        }

        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(getActivity()));
            parentList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            addVal = valueReturn(dummyVal, period, parentList);
        }

        public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
            Activity contextACT;

            public MyListAdapter(Activity context) {
                super(context, R.layout.nrrow_of_list_lesson, dummyVal);
                this.contextACT = context;
            }

            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflator = contextACT.getLayoutInflater();
                final View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.nrrow_of_list_lesson,
                        null);
                final TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.lessonname);
                period = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.ssperiodeditText);
                final Button increase = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.ssincrease);
                final Button decrease = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.ssdecrease);
                increase.setId(position);
                decrease.setId((dummyVal.length) + position);

                final Integer currentQuant = Integer.parseInt(period.getText()
                        .toString());

                increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        increase.getId();
                        Log.w("button value", "" + increase.getId());
                        if (currentQuant != 0) {
                            period.setText(new Integer(currentQuant + 1).toString());
                        }

                    }
                });

            decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Log.w("button value1", " " + decrease.getId());
                    decrease.getId();
                    if (currentQuant != 1) {
                        period.setText(new Integer(currentQuant - 1).toString());
                    }

                }
            });


            return (row);

        }

    }

    void setParent(NRSessionFragmentHolder parent) {
        this.parentobj = parent;
    }

    public int valueReturn(String[] dummyVal, EditText period2,
            ListView parentList) {
        Integer add = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= dummyVal.length; i++) {
            View temp = null;
            temp = parentList.getChildAt(i);
            while (!(temp == null)) {
                add = Integer.parseInt(period2.getText().toString());

            }
        }
        return add;
    }

}
```

Comment: Link to what? What is your question?

Comment: its just tat i want to retrieve all the value present in each editbox

Comment: i have added my code. i'm using fragment method

Comment: i want to get the total value of the editText into this

Comment: [addVal = valueReturn(dummyVal, period, parentList);]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your Button's `onClickListener()` to get the adapter of the listView, convert it to a List and sum up the contents of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I figured out a way to do this.... It turned out to be very simple.... here is the code.... Here I have used a ListView just to substitute the value....

```
 parentList=(ListView)findViewByid(R.id.list);

 public int getTvValue() {
    View view;
    String[] edVal = new String[parentList.getChildCount()];
    int val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parentList.getCount(); i++) {
        view = parentList.getChildAt(i);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TVmid);
        edVal[i] = tv.getText().toString();
        val = Integer.parseInt(edVal[i]) + val;
    }
    return val;

}
```